# How to configure a Telegram bot in a private chat

Tags: bots, telegram

I want to add some bots to my Telegram supergroup, such as a welcome bot and a statistics bot.

I see there are ready-made bots (like @combot) that I can just add to my group and configure.

My problem is that I already have users in my group and I don't really want them to see all the mess of the configuration chat with the bot, and also I don't want them to access the bot of course!

Is there a way to accomplish this?